# In (Free) Pascal, can a function return a value that can be modified without dereference?

Tags: pointers, pascal, freepascal

In Pascal, I understand that one could create a function returning a pointer which can be dereferenced and then assign a value to that, such as in the following (obnoxiously useless) example:

```pascal
type ptr = ^integer;
var d: integer;

function f(x: integer): ptr;
    begin
        f := @x;
    end;

begin
    f(d)^ := 4;
end.
```

And now `d` is 4.

(The actual usage is to access part of a quite complicated array of records data structure. I know that a class would be better than an array of nested records, but it isn't my code (it's TeX: The Program) and was written before Pascal implementations supported object-orientation. The code was written using essentially a language built on top of Pascal that added macros which expand before the compiler sees them. Thus you could define some macro `m` that takes an argument `x` and expands into `thearray[x + 1].f1.f2` instead of writing that every time; the usage would be `m(x) := somevalue`. I want to replicate this functionality with a function instead of a macro.)

However, is it possible to achieve this functionality without the `^` operator? Can a function `f` be written such that `f(x) := y` (no caret) assigns the value `y` to `x`? I know that this is stupid and the answer is probably no, but I just (a) don't really like the look of it and (b) am trying to mimic exactly the form of the macro I mentioned above.

Comment: I suppose you meant to write `f := @x;` in the function body. But even that won't do what you think it should do, it would return the address of the local integer that is x, not d. You'd have to declare "x" a "var" parameter.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You're right; thank you for pointing that out. To be fair, I don't actually use Pascal at all, and I only have a background in Python, which barely supports the concept of a pointer at all.

Comment: You're welcome. ...  Well, in pascal you can't assign to a function return.

Comment: This won't work in any language, since you dereference a pointer to a value passed by value, which doesn't exist after termination of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References are not first class objects in Pascal, unlike languages such as C++ or D. So the simple answer is that you cannot directly achieve what you want.

Using a pointer as you illustrated is one way to achieve the same effect although in real code you'd need to return the address of an object whose lifetime extends beyond that of the function. In your code that is not the case because the argument `x` is only valid until the function returns.

You could use an enhanced record with operator overloading to encapsulate the pointer, and so encapsulate the pointer dereferencing code. That may be a good option, but it very much depends on your overall problem, of which we do not have sight.

Comment: Note that you might have to set a specific [mode directive](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Operator_overloading).